# Inserting into a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys I know that this is probably just a simple sql statement but I can not figure out the problem. It adds the user to the database but it will not add the firstname of the user. If I switch the sql statement around for example have username and email before first name it then does not insert the password switches name and email. Does anyone know how to fix this problem and have all of the information inserted into the proper tables in the database.

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

  $db_server = "server";
       $db_username = "name";
       $db_password = "pass";

       $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

               $database = "Account_Holder"; 

              $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
        if (!$er) 
        {
         print ("Error - Could not select the database");
         exit;
        }        

        // table name
$tbl_name=Account_Holder;

// Random confirmation code
//$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=$_POST['username'];



        // Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(firstname, username, email, password)VALUES('$firstname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "You have been added to the database! You may now log on using your username."
       ?>
        <a href ="login.html"> Login Page </a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please give us your sql table structure? Do you have any id fields?

Comment: What is your database structure like and what is some sample data that you are trying to insert?  Does any of your sample data have single quotes?  And, have you looked in the log files for error messages?

Comment: @Allie one good way of troubleshooting in development environment is to enable display/logging of errors so that you know where you are failing and what is causing the failure. So try to capture the sql error with `mysql_error()` when you perform the `mysql_query()` like `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and see what it says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, nothing seems wrong, except major security flaws. Perhaps you wrote some value from the `$_POST` array wrong. Do a `print_r` on the array to see the exact names.

First of all, your code is extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_stirng) on every of your user input. You can **never** trust any user input.

You should make your SQL look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (firstname, username, email, password) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."')";
```

I am unsure whether the ommited spaces will have any effect on the query, but its good to have to make it easier to read. If you're unsure about whats wrong, you should always use [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) to show the error, like this:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Third and last thing. You should **never** store passwords as plaintext in the database. For the love of god, please [hash](http://php.net/md5) it or something :-)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you mean `$_POST['firstname']` rather than `$_POST['firstName']`.

By the way, you really need to sanitize user input before putting it into a database the way you are here.  This code would be trivial to write a SQL injection exploit against.  For a start, run the user-supplied values through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  As it stands now, your code will blow not work if the user input contains an apostrophe/single quote.

If you think the problem is that the query is generating an error, use `mysql_error()` right after `mysql_query()` to see if there was an error.  It will return an empty string if there was no error.  Otherwise, it will return the error.

Also, I would strongly recommend storing the password using a hashing function in MySQL (using `PASSWORD()`) if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem.  Your first name variable has a capitol 'N' for name.  Change your code to either of these and it should work fine.

`$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(firstname, username, email, password)VALUES('$firstName', '$username', '$email', '$password')";`

or

`$firstname=$_POST['firstName'];`

Also, I would also suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) over regular MySQL.  But that's just me...

Comment: Don't know why this got down voted. This seems to be the obvious first of the issues. There may also be a problem with the POST variable name as Trott pointed out though.